# Gettting log4j error ERROR StatusLogger "No log4j2 configuration file found" while adding jmeter dependencies to my pom.xml

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, citrus-framework

Here is my pom.xml. I am getting log4j errors and no information is being printed after getting the errors could any one help on these. I have seen many similar questions like this but none of them are working fine

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.walmart.testframrework</groupId>
      <artifactId>testframework</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
         <exclusions> 
         <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
    </dependency> 

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>

            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


     <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.elega9t</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-jms-skip-jndi</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency> -->

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
      <artifactId>citrus-java-dsl</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.consol.citrus/citrus-jms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>citrus-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.25</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.25</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
          <artifactId>citrus-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

my application is running fine until jmeter dependencies are not added. but after adding these dependencies it was printing the error like

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file://dwshome-a.homeoffice.wal-mart.com/dwsuserdata$/avada2/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.10.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file://dwshome-a.homeoffice.wal-mart.com/dwsuserdata$/avada2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Here are the  jmeter dependencies that are defined in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version> 
</dependency> 
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.elega9t</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-jms-skip-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `log4j2.xml` under `<maven_module>/src/test/resources` ?

Here is an example configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <Properties>
        <Property name="path">target</Property>
        <Property name="logFileName">integration-tests-logs</Property>
        <Property name="logPattern">%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5.5p %28.28c{2}| %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="logfile" fileName="${path}/${logFileName}.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="logfile"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This basically configures logging in the console and generates a log file in the `/target` folder everytime you run your integration tests.